# How to leverage concurrency for processing large array of data in rust?

Tags: rust, frontend, tauri

I am a javascript developer and I am building a desktop application using Tauri. I am used to single-threaded languages and trying to get comfortable with the concept of concurrency.

My problem can be summarized as follows. I receive a JSON array from the backend of length 500. I loop through this array and perform some asynchronous operations like making a network call. In the end, I aggregate, structure, and return the data. This entire process takes around 25-35 seconds on my machine.

I wanted to leverage the concept of concurrency to reduce the time required for this operation. One possible solution that I thought of, was to create n number of threads, let's say 8, and parallelly process the data.

```
async fun main(){
   // creating variables which will hold final structured data
   let app_data;
   let app_to_bundle_map;

   // create 8 threads
   let thread_1 = thread::spawn(|| {})
   let thread_2 = thread::spawn(|| {})
   //.. so on

   for i in 1..500{
        let thread_assigned = i % 8
        match thread_assigned {
             1 => { 
                  // process_data() on thread 1 and insert into app_data & app_to_bundle_map. 
                  // But how do I assign process_data() to the thread's closure? 
                  // How do I make sure thread 1 is available for use?
             }
             2 => {
                  // process_data() on thread 2 and insert into app_data & app_to_bundle_map
             }
             _ => {
                  // process_data() on thread _ and insert into app_data & app_to_bundle_map
             }
        }
   }
}

fun process_data(item: String, data: &Data){
    // perform some heavy operations like
    make_network_call(item.url)
    // perform more operations and modify the function argument
    more_processing()
}

async fun make_a_network_call(url: String) -> String{
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build().unwrap();
    let mut _res: Result<Response, Error> = client.get(url).send().await;

    match _res{
        OK(_res) => {
            // return response
        }
        Err(_res) => {
            format!(r#"{{"error": "{placeholder}"}}"#, placeholder = _res.to_string())
        }
    }

}
```

Another option I thought of was dividing my data of size 500 into 8 parts and then processing them parallelly. Is this a better approach? Or are both the approaches wrong, if so, what do you suggest is the correct method to solve such problems in rust? Overall, my final goal is to reduce the time from 25-35 seconds to less than 10 seconds. Looking forward to everybody's insights. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency is hard [citation needed]. What you are trying to do here is manually handling it. That of course *could* work, but it will be a pain, especially if you are a beginner. Luckily there are **fantastic** libraries already out there that provide handling concurrency part for you. You should looking if they already provide what you need.From your description I am not quite sure if you are CPU or IO bound.

If you are CPU bound you should look at [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) crate. It allows to easily iterate in parallel over some iterator.

If you are IO bound you should look at `async` rust. There are many libraries, that allow to do many things, but I would recommend [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) to begin with. It is production-ready and has great emphasis put on networking. You would need however to learn a bit about async rust, as it requires different thinking model than normal synchronous code.

And regardless of which one you choose you should familiarize yourself with *channels*. They are a great and easy tool for passing data around, including from one thread to another.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me move one step closer towards my goal. I ended up using rayon, and it was working great, until I realised that there are network calls being made inside the for loop. So now Ill start from scratch and try using tokio.

Comment: @JaskaranSingh good luck. If it is your first time with async rust I would recommend reading Tokio's [tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial).